# Can't use a style defined in library(module) from another module

Tags: android, xml, styles

We are developing android SDK library, and we have some styles defined under the library resources directory, The problem is that when we try to open an activity/fragment in the other module that uses in its xml view style that was defined in our library the app crashes with exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 3 ...etc
```

Anyone faced this before or tell me How could I use styles from another module in my module?